# Incase one of the 2 tables that I am CROSS joining is having duplicates, will there be duplicates in the output as well?

Tags: sql, teradata

Table1 :

| Col1 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Table2 :

| Col1 |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| B |

what will be the o/p of : select Table1.col1 from Table1 cross join Table2.col1 from Table2;

Comment: Yes - remember, a cross join is "every row to every row". If you want something like "every value to every value", you'll need to do a cross join of distinct query results instead of raw tables, for example.

Comment: Why don't you simply try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result set of a `CROSS JOIN` where one table has 2 rows and the other 3 will always have six rows.  A `CROSS JOIN` produces a Cartesian product, where each row in one table is paired with each row in the other.

In your case:

```
1    A
1    B
1    B
2    A
2    B
2    B
```

So, there are duplicates, if that is what you are asking.